# Open and hide from view an excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I have this routine which opens and hides a workbook that I installed for my teammates for them to access the macros I created.

It is built to first check if the workbook is already open, however, I recently noticed that if they run it more then once there will be two of the same workbook open.

[image: unhide workbooks]

This is problematic because my teammates might occasionally unhide this document to access some of the contents on the worksheet and they get confused when they see two of the same workbook.

I tried removing the `.NewWindow` however then it starts hiding the wrong windows.

See my full code below.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Function IsWBOpen(WorkbookName As String) As Boolean
' check if WorkbookName is already opened

    Dim wb As Variant
    Dim NAME As String, searchfor As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    searchfor = LCase(WorkbookName)
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        pos = InStrRev(wb.NAME, ".")
        If pos = 0 Then                           ' new wb, no extension
            NAME = LCase(wb.NAME)
        Else
            NAME = LCase(Left(wb.NAME, pos - 1))  ' strip extension
        End If
        If NAME = searchfor Then
            IsWBOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb
    IsWBOpen = False
End Function


Sub openmacros()

    If IsWBOpen("RP Macro Wrkbk") Then
        GoTo Message:
        Else
        Set RP = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="file:///\\FPSFILES1\ReviewPricing\Macro Data\RP Macro Wrkbk.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True).NewWindow
        ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    End If
Message:
    MsgBox "RP Macros enabled", _
                    vbOKOnly, "RP Macros"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Consider using a custom add-in

A first solution I would purpose to you is to create an [add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview) with your tools. I won't get into the details of how to do that, but this would add many benefits to your users, one of them being is that they won't need to open it each time.

You'll need to expose to them any content you need to as you won't have access to `show` the workbook.

### The Issues with your Function

When you open your workbook, you are also calling [`.NewWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newwindow), which creates a copy of the newly opened workbook.

```vb
Set RP = Workbooks.Open( _
         Filename:="file:///\\FPSFILES1\ReviewPricing\Macro Data\RP Macro Wrkbk.xlsb", _
         ReadOnly:=True).NewWindow
```

Removing the `.NewWindow` should prevent this from happening.

### Side notes

Your functions are more complex then they need to.

Checking if the workbook exists assumes that the extension is not going to be provided. Why not use the [`like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator). That way, the name passed in can use wildcard characters to give it more flexibility and make the function easier to follow.

```vb
Public Function IsWorkbookOpen(ByVal workbookName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If UCase(wb.NAME) Like UCase(workbookName) Then
            IsWorkbookOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb
End Function
```

Your second function has an unnecessary `goto` statement. Moving your conditional around would clean it up a bit and be easier to follow.

```vb
Public Sub OpenMacros()
    If Not IsWorkbookOpen("RP Macro Wrkbk*") Then
        Set RP = Workbooks.Open( _
                    Filename:="file:///\\FPSFILES1\ReviewPricing\Macro Data\RP Macro Wrkbk.xlsb", _
                    ReadOnly:=True)
    End If
    MsgBox "RP Macros enabled", vbOKOnly, "RP Macros"
End Sub
```

Last note, `RP` looks to be some sort of global Variable. Not sure what it's used for, but as much as you can avoid using global variables unless there is a strong reason to do so.

Comment: This does not address my question at all. Thanks for simplifying my code, but where is my ```ActiveWindow.Visible = False```? Thats the basis of the question. There is a reason why I had a ```.NewWindow``` in there.